# Can I hardwire a 10A appliance into a 20A circuit using 14ga?

Tags: electrical

In California, The breaker is 20A and the structural wiring is 12ga. Can I hardwire in an appliance to this circuit using 14ga bx cable? Or must I use 12ga?

The appliance is a water circulation pump that came with a 14ga cord which plugs into a receptacle. Rather than a bunch of plugs for these in my utility room I want to hardwire them in.

Comment: Did the 14g cable come with/mounted to the appliance or is it some old cable you have lying around?

Comment: What do you mean by "a bunch of plugs"? Are you installing more than one pump? What else is going on there?  Just curious, but is this a HW recirc pump?   Or why else would you be recirculating water?

Comment: HW circulation pump. When I bought the house it is setup plugged into a receptacle. It's in a utility room which is a mess so I'm trying to clean things up. I have lots of 14ga on hand, and 14 is just easier to work with

Comment: I guess "a bunch of plugs" for *all* the things that may be installed that are like this

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Any building wiring you add is subject to 310.15(B)(16) and 240.4(D).  It must be appropriately sized for the breaker, so in your case must be #12 Cu or #10 AL.

Appliance cords going to a plug-in are certified by UL under a different set of rules.  Because a) they are in open-air, not packed in a wall cavity and b) they are directly observable by users, who will spot thermal degradation.

As far as cord-and-plug connection (or lack thereof), you must follow the manufacturer's instructions (which are approved by UL as part of approving the appliance)...  as well as Article 400 (particularly 400.7 and 400.8 which state where flexible cordage can be used, and where it cannot).

Answer (score 3):

No, unless you downsize the breaker to 15A and mark the wires with a label that says there is 14ga as part of the circuit. But more to your point, how long a length of wire are you talking about? I can't imagine it could be very long.  The cost difference between 14 and 12 isn't all that much and you get the added benefit less voltage drop.

Depending upon the "appliance" (what is it?) code may require a dedicated circuit. Many hardwired appliances do. If it's not going to be inspected, you can do it and it's probably safe, but bear in mind that when you go to sell your house, an eagle eyed home inspector may call it out.

Comment: It's a water circulation pump which came with a 14g plug, which goes into a receptacle. I prefer to have it hardwired.

Comment: So your intent is to cut off the plug and hardwire it?  Why? The rules change a lot for hardwired stuff, esp. regarding wire type and size.  The pump cord is probably type S or SJ,  I dk for sure, but I don't believe it's OK to hardwire those. Hopefully the experts here will chime in.   Just a personal opinion:  Some dishwashers are intended to be hard wired, others have a cord with a plug.  If I'm installing a DW without a cord, I'll buy a heavy duty appliance cord and use that to a dedicated outlet under the sink. Much easier installation and later replacement, if needed.

Comment: This pump has a knockout in its housing which is currently fitted with a Romex clamp, but instead of Romex they have used an appliance cord. I want to remove the appliance cord and NM clamp and replace with bx and appropriate clamp. This is pretty standard stuff, I just wasn't sure about wire guage requirements in this case.

Comment: OK, got it. so you'll be entirely removing the plugged cable.   Just go with 12/2 to keep things simple.  Yeah, it's harder to work with than 14, but since it's on a 20A circuit, just go with it, IMHO.

Comment: Yes, must use #12 AWG.